# Using lean + cursor with find query in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to find nice way to use streams in mongoose with lean() and cursor.
At moment this is my code which is getting users from mongo which really creates new users array

```
try {
    const userList = User.find().lean().cursor();
    let users = [];

    userList.on('data', (user) => users.push(user));
    userList.on('error', () => {});
    userList.on('end', () => res.status(200).send(users));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

I find this solution little bit weird and maybe there is better implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `for loop iterator` technique:

```
for await (const doc of Model.find([{ $sort: { name: 1 } }]).cursor()) {
  console.log(doc.name);
}
```

here is [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/querycursor.html) for the method and the cursor

read an [article](https://thecodebarbarian.com/getting-started-with-async-iterators-in-node-js) by Valeriy Karpov (mongoose author) for more in-depth explanation of how it works.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at http://highlandjs.org/.

With highland the code would look something like this (not tested):

```
var _h = require('highland');

_h(User.find().lean().cursor())
.toArray(function(users) {
  res.status(200).send(users)
});
```

Comment: I think I sorted a problem. You solution is only putting additional complexly and dependency for stuff which is not needed

Comment: @MarceliJanowski could you share your solution as an answer to this question